# Mapreduce with HCATALOG integration with oozie in MAPR

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, hue, hcatalog

I have written a mapreduce program that reads the data from hive table using HCATLOG and writes into HBase. This is a map only job with no reducers. I have ran the program from command line and it works as expected(Created a fat jar to avoid Jar issues). I wanted to integrate it oozie (with Help of HUE) . I have two options to run it

1. Use Mapreduce Action
2. Use Java Action

Since my Mapreduce program has a driver method that holds the below code

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.schema.HCatSchema;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat;

public class HBaseValdiateInsertDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String dbName = "Test";
    String tableName = "emp";
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    args = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "HBase Get Put Demo");
    job.setInputFormatClass(HCatInputFormat.class);
    HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, dbName, tableName, null);

    job.setJarByClass(HBaseValdiateInsertDriver.class);

    job.setMapperClass(HBaseValdiateInsert.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("maprfs:///user/input"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("maprfs:///user/output"));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    }
}
```

How do i specify the driver method in oozie, All that i can see is to specify mapper and reducer class.Can someone guide me how do i set the properties ?

Using java action i can specify my driver class as the main class and get this executed , but i face errors like table not found, HCATLOG jars not found etc. I have include hive-site.xml in the workflow(Using Hue) but i feel the system is not able to pick up the properties. Can someone advise me what all do i have to take care of, are there any other configuration properties that i need to include ?

Also the sample program i referred in cloudera website uses

```
HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, InputJobInfo.create(dbName,
                inputTableName, null));
```

where as i use the below (I dont see a method that accept the above input

```
HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, dbName, tableName, null);
```

Below is my mapper code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Durability;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTableInterface;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.HCatRecord;



public class HBaseValdiateInsert extends Mapper<WritableComparable, HCatRecord, Text, Text> {

    static HTableInterface table;
    static HTableInterface inserted;
    private String hbaseDate = null;
    String existigValue=null;
    List<Put> putList = new ArrayList<Put>();


    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException {

                Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
                String tablename = "dev_arch186";
        Utils.getHBConnection();
        table = Utils.getTable(tablename);
        table.setAutoFlushTo(false);
    }
    @Override
    public void cleanup(Context context) {
        try {
            table.put(putList);
            table.flushCommits();
            table.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Utils.closeConnection();
    }



    @Override
    public void map(WritableComparable key, HCatRecord value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                String name_hive = (String) value.get(0);
                String id_hive = (String) value.get(1);

                String rec[] = test.toString().split(",");
        Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(name_hive));

        existigValue=getOneRecord(Bytes.toBytes("Info"),Bytes.toBytes("name"),name_hive);
        if (existigValue.equalsIgnoreCase("NA") || !existigValue.equalsIgnoreCase(id_hive)) {
            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rec[0]));
            put.add(Bytes.toBytes("Info"),
                    Bytes.toBytes("name"),
                    Bytes.toBytes(rec[1]));
            put.setDurability(Durability.SKIP_WAL);
            putList.add(put);
            if(putList.size()>25000){
                table.put(putList);
                table.flushCommits();
            }
        }

    }


    public String getOneRecord(byte[] columnFamily, byte[] columnQualifier, String rowKey)
            throws IOException {
        Get get = new Get(rowKey.getBytes());
        get.setMaxVersions(1);
        Result rs = table.get(get);
        rs.getColumn(columnFamily, columnQualifier);
        System.out.println(rs.containsColumn(columnFamily, columnQualifier));
        KeyValue result = rs.getColumnLatest(columnFamily,columnQualifier);

        if (rs.containsColumn(columnFamily, columnQualifier))
            return (Bytes.toString(result.getValue()));
        else
            return "NA";
    }

    public boolean columnQualifierExists(String tableName, String ColumnFamily,
            String ColumnQualifier, String rowKey) throws IOException  {
        Get get = new Get(rowKey.getBytes());
        Result rs = table.get(get);
        return(rs.containsColumn(ColumnFamily.getBytes(),ColumnQualifier.getBytes()));
    }

}
```

Note:
I use MapR (M3) Cluster with HUE as the interface for oozie.
Hive Version : 1-0
HCAT Version: 1-0

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to initialize HCatInputFormat from Oozie mapreduce action.
But I have a workaround as below.

Created LazyHCatInputFormat by extending HCatInputFormat.
Override the getJobInfo method, to handle initalization. This will be called as part of getSplits(..) call.

```
    private static void lazyInit(Configuration conf){
    try{

        if(conf==null){
            conf = new Configuration(false);
        }
        conf.addResource(new Path(System.getProperty("oozie.action.conf.xml")));
        conf.addResource(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("hive-config.xml"));

        String databaseName = conf.get("LazyHCatInputFormat.databaseName");
        String tableName = conf.get("LazyHCatInputFormat.tableName");
        String partitionFilter = conf.get("LazyHCatInputFormat.partitionFilter");

        setInput(conf, databaseName, tableName);
        //setFilter(partitionFilter);

        //System.out.println("After lazyinit : "+conf.get("mapreduce.lib.hcat.job.info"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("*** LAZY INIT FAILED ***");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static InputJobInfo getJobInfo(Configuration conf)
        throws IOException {
    String jobString = conf.get("mapreduce.lib.hcat.job.info");
    if (jobString == null) {
        lazyInit(conf);
        jobString = conf.get("mapreduce.lib.hcat.job.info");
        if(jobString == null){
            throw new IOException("job information not found in JobContext. HCatInputFormat.setInput() not called?");   
        }
    }
    return (InputJobInfo) HCatUtil.deserialize(jobString);
}
```

In the oozie map-redcue action, configured as below.

```
              <property>
                <name>mapreduce.job.inputformat.class</name>
                <value>com.xyz.LazyHCatInputFormat</value>
          </property>
          <property>
                <name>LazyHCatInputFormat.databaseName</name>
                <value>HCAT DatabaseNameHere</value>
          </property>
           <property>
                <name>LazyHCatInputFormat.tableName</name>
                <value>HCAT TableNameHere</value>
          </property>
```

This might not be the best implementation, but a quick hack to make it work.